# What is Facebook's rule for incentivizing invites?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-invite

I’m developing a Facebook game and I’m currently working on a process to give players the ability to invite friends to play.

From reading Facebook’s docs I understood that you’re not allowed to reward person A simply for sending an invite to person B, but you can reward person A if person B accepts the invite and joins the game.

I’ve been developing my game to comply with this rule (currently I only reward senders of invites whenever their invites get accepted), but after researching this subject online I found this question: https://www.quora.com/Is-Facebooks-policy-against-apps-incentivizing-users-to-invite-friends-still-active

This states that you can reward someone for simply sending invites, as long as you give them an alternative way to get that reward (in this example the alternative way is by paying 15 gold coins). From reading Facebook’s docs I wouldn’t have thought this is possible, but it appears that this method is being used by Zynga Poker.

This is really confusing to me, and I was wondering if anyone here would be able to tell me what exactly the rule is?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse, 4.5 – check the example images behind the question mark. That is the only relevant thing here – whether you’re providing other ways for users to get the same thing, doesn’t matter.

Comment: Hi @CBroe thanks for your comment, I've set up my game to comply with the rules in your link, I'm just wondering how Zynga Poker are able to run the incentive they're running in the link in my question, from reading Facebook's docs it appears as though they're breaking the rules, is this correct?